# Reference XML Schema element into same XML schema's element as value

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a use case to prepare XML schema to support following XML strcture and reference xml element name as a value in another xml element:

**Initial Message**:

```
<Message> 
  <Name>Person1</Name>
  <LatLong>43.472429, -80.544429</LatLong>
  <DeviceId>34563623567</DeviceId>
<UpdatedFields>
</UpdatedFields>
</Message>
```

**Update to initial message**

```
  <Message> 
     <Name>Person1</Name>
     <LatLong>43.644306, -79.338044</LatLong>
     <DeviceId>34563623567</DeviceId>
     <UpdatedFields>
        <Field>LatLong</Field>
     </UpdatedFields>
</Message>
```

I tried using XML Schema "ref" and complexType's mixed="true" however could not find a way to reference element name in the value of another xml element.

**How can xml element name be referenced in another xml element but as a value of that element? Is this doable in XML Schema?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Appears there is no way to do this in same XML schema.

So I'm going ahead and adding an Enumeration with all the fields of the XSD to reference the field names as a value.